# Agradecimientos por el apoyo a la conferencia Arquitectura de Big Data en Bucaramanga

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales, comunidad

El pasado 20 de septiembre, tuvimos un encuentro sobre [Arquitectura de Big Data](https://www.meetup.com/es-ES/PythonBucaramanga/events/252909094/) en la ciudad de Bucaramanga-Colombia, evento en el cual stackoverflow en español (SOes) se vinculó con fabulosos premios y regalos.

[image: Meetup]

Answer (score 6):

**A continuación el resumen de como se dieron las cosas:**

Iniciando ...

[image: Iniciando]

Aunque esperábamos más o menos unas 30 personas, al final tuvimos una asistencia de 21 personas, tal vez porqué la fecha del evento coincidió con las ferias y fiestas de la ciudad.

Acá con un poco de nervios al principio, pero todo fluyó luego :)

[image: Presentador]

Llego el momento del intermedio, espacio para comer y socializar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora todo el grupo "foto pal face"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llegó el momento de los premios y regalos ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La metodología fue sencilla, pedimos que registraran en una hoja, identificados con un número consecutivo, el nombre, el Id de SOes, y que respondieran si tenían una reputación > 15, tres personas dijeron que si, entonces ellos fueron los primeros en elegir premio, para el resto que tenían cuenta creada generamos números aleatorios para el orden de elegir regalo, al final se rifo un último regalo entre las personas que no tenían cuenta. (Casi nos alcanza para todos, únicamente faltaron tres).

Acá la foto con los regalos (Salimos un poco tarde, entonces no están todos, porqué a algunos se les complicaba el transporte)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sentimos que el evento salio bien y cumplimos con el objetivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> En general tuvimos un muy buen balance, muchas gracias por ayudarnos a construir comunidad

Comment: Ahora ya tienen una idea de las cosas que sintoniza el santa de futurama sobre Bucaramanga ;). https://www.instagram.com/p/BkZKT2AA1wU/?hl=es&taken-by=robinjp23

Comment: Excelente, felicitaciones!